# Rendering Transparent Blocks in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm rendering 3D terrain with cubes and I need to render water transparently.

My solution for this, after some research, was to separate the water cubes into one buffer and the solid blocks into the other buffer, then in my fragment shader, I'm using:

```
uniform float transparency;
```

in my rendering code:

```
shader.setFloat("transparency", 1.0f);
glBindVertexArray(solidVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, solidPoints.size());

shader.setFloat("transparency", 0.3f);
glBindVertexArray(transparentVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, transparentPoints.size());
```

and then in my Fragment Shader

```
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D atlas;
uniform float transparency;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(atlas, TexCoord);
    FragColor.w = transparency;
}
```

However, the water is still solid, is there a better approach to drawing transparent shapes in front of solids? Or, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set blending mode for the transparent shape as well:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```